# Dataframe Key Error Column not in index

Tags: pandas

I am reading an excel file into pandas using `pd.ExcelFile.`
It reads correctly and I can print the dataframe. But when I try to select a subset of columns like:

```
subdf= origdf[['CUTOMER_ID','ASSET_BAL']]
```

I get error:

```
 KeyError: "['CUTOMER_ID' 'ASSET_BAL'] not in index"
```

Do I need to define some kind of index here? When I printed the df, I verified that the columns are there.

Comment: The best check it `print (origdf.columns.tolist())`

Comment: maybe traling whitespaces problem, maybe encoding problem

Comment: easy check is to to print(origdf.columns) to see the actual names of your columns. Also, the KeyError you shared with us suggest that there is no comma between the column names on your slicing, something doesn't add up

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ensure that the columns actually exist in the dataframe. For example, you have written CUTOMER and not CUSTOMER, which I assume is the correct name.

You can verify the column names by using `list(origdf.columns.values)`.

Comment: Thx, I had hidden symbol in the column name and I have seen it with your code!

Comment: the same error may appear if you try to add column without actually assign some values to it. For adding empty column without this error you need something like this: `df["column"] = ""`

Answer (score 0):

And for when you *don't* have a typo problem, here is a solution:

Use `loc` instead,

```
subdf= origdf.loc[:, ['CUSTOMER_ID','ASSET_BAL']].values
```

(I'd be glad to learn why this one works, though.)